# Detect a proxy change vuejs3

Tags: vuejs3, reactive

I don't know how to detect a proxy object change without display it.

I Use async API call to set a proxy object (from a parent component).

In my child component, I use it like this

```
computed: {
  user() { return dataProxy.getCurrentUser() // return a proxy object }
}
updated: {
  console.debug(this.user)
  if(this.user.id !== undefined) {
    loadUserDetails(this.user)
  }
}
```

When the component is mounted, `updated` method is called and the console display an empty proxy object (ok)
But when the proxy object is updated from api response, the `updated` method is never called.

Now, If I add `{{user}}` on my template, the `updated` method is called after the API response with the right content.

how to detect a proxy object change without display it ?

Answer (score -2):

You should use a `watch` function:

```
    watch: {
        user(newUser) {
            console.log('user changed:', newUser);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, it works ! But why someone added a negative vote ?

Comment: lol I have no idea